# How to force React to update a text node if it was manually edited in the DOM?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a text node that is being manually edited in the DOM that is not being updated by React when the `render()` method is called.

To demonstrate using an example from the official [React website](https://reactjs.org/):

```js
class TodoApp extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = { items: [], text: '' };
    this.handleChange = this.handleChange.bind(this);
    this.handleSubmit = this.handleSubmit.bind(this);
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <h3>TODO</h3>
        <TodoList items={this.state.items} />
        <form onSubmit={this.handleSubmit}>
          <label htmlFor="new-todo">
            What needs to be done?
          </label>
          <input
            id="new-todo"
            onChange={this.handleChange}
            value={this.state.text}
          />
          <button>
            Add #{this.state.items.length + 1}
          </button>
        </form>
      </div>
    );
  }

  handleChange(e) {
    this.setState({ text: e.target.value });
  }

  handleSubmit(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    if (this.state.text.length === 0) {
      return;
    }
    const newItem = {
      text: this.state.text,
      id: Date.now()
    };
    this.setState(state => ({
      items: state.items.concat(newItem),
      text: ''
    }));
  }
}

class TodoList extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <ul>
        {/* Note: using contentEditable only for the purpose of this demo */}
        {this.props.items.map(item => (
          <li key={item.id} contentEditable={true}>{item.text}</li>
        ))}
      </ul>
    );
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(
  <TodoApp />,
  document.getElementById('todos-example')
);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<div id="todos-example"></div>
```

I have added `contentEditable` only for this demo (I'm not trying to update the todo item), when you add a new item and then edit it directly in the DOM and then you add another item, why the previously edited item is not being updated to its previous state?

**Edit:**

**Why am I doing this?**
I have an app where the user can click on an edit button and start directly editing the text, I add the `contentEditable` attribute and use `onInput` to store the edited text and update the parent's state using a function passed as a prop, what I want to solve is when the user cancels the edit, I want to revert back the previous text, what I'm currently doing is directly editing the `innerText` of this element to set the previous value because it's not being updated by React.

Comment: That is because even though `TodoList` is changed, the old `<li>` elements are not re-rendered because their keys are the same.

Answer (score 1):

You have this problem because React has a virtual DOM where it compares the changes. When you modify the real DOM, React don't knows that you modified it, so when it compares its virtual DOM with the new `render()` see no changes for that element, so is not re-rendered.

If you have control over all the HTML in your React compontents, Do not modify the DOM directly, never. You should add event listeners on user actions (keypress in this case) to catch them and update the component state accordingly. If you do so, you must understand how [React virtual DOM works](https://reactjs.org/docs/faq-internals.html).

Comment: So should I find another way to provide the user with a way to edit the text? I'm currently setting the element as editable when the user clicks on an edit button, if the user cancels the edit I want to revert to the previous value which I'm currently doing manually by setting the `innerText` property of this element which is not an elegant solution.

Comment: Yes, as I said, you must rely on user events, as keypress, keydown, keyup, focus, blur and such. You have a lot to look for. What you are actually searching for is for "contenteditable in React", which I'm pretty sure has been already asked and answered here.

Answer (score 1):

If `state` or `props` remains unchanged - component  will not re-render. So, your manually edit has to update some state if you want component to re-render.

So, I believe that you can do the same thing you are doing - but "react way", not manually. Othervise, what is the point of using react?

#### Edit

If contenteditable is "must have" (you can't toggle between div and text area), if I were you - will add:

1. `tempEdit` to state or `selected` - if you need to hold object in that part of the state. If you choose object, you can keep original text here as well - which you can use latter if user choose to cancel editing
2. add cancel button for canceling edits
3. optional: if element with contenteditable attr can accept `onBlur` use it to revert text in edited element

Comment: Yes you're right about doing it the "react way", I've updated my question with the reason I'm doing this, I want the user to edit the text directly but revert to the old text if the user cancels this action.

Answer (score 0):

I solved this using the `key` attribute to force React to re-create the DOM element, I don't know if this is the best way, but this is the cleanest way that I found that let me revert the text of a `contentEditable` element when the user cancel editing after changing the text.

I have an `edit` state property that I toggle to make the element editable, so I added a `key` with the string value of this property:

```js
<p
  contentEditable={this.state.edit}
  suppressContentEditableWarning="true"
  onInput={this.handleInput}
  onKeyDown={this.handleKeyDown}
  key={String(this.state.edit)}
>
  {item.text}
</p>
```

This has one drawback, React will re-create the element on every change of the `edit` state.

Eventually `contentEditable` is not the best solution for all the cases, but when you need to provide an editing solution without adding new elements this can do the job.